# Given n flips, what is the expected number of times the sequence HT shows up?

Tags: recursion

Suppose a fair coin is flipped $n$ times - what is the expected number of appearances of the sequence HT?

I know it's $\sqrt n$, can anyone provide an explanation why this is true?

Comment: Are my edits consistent with the spirit of your question?

Comment: I don't think the answer is $\sqrt n$... was that perhaps some kind of approximation? I ran a simulation using 500,000 trials of 16 flips each and got an average of $3.75$ occurrences, not $\sqrt 16=4$.

Comment: it might be, using stirling's approximation i think

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1$ to $n-1$, let $X_k=1$ if we get an H on the $k$-th toss and a T on the $(k+1)$-th toss. Then the number of times HT appears is $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n-1}$.

If $X$ is the number of appearances of HT, then $X=X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1}$, so by the linearity of expectation we have $E(X)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_{n-1})$.

Easily, $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{4}$, since $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus $E(X)=\frac{n-1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

With probability ${1\over2}$ the next toss will be different from the previous one, and there are $n-1$ places where such a change can occur. Therefore we may expect ${n-1\over2}$ changes in all, and half of them will be $HT$, by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Consider all sequences of n Hs and Ts. How many HTs are there in all?

---

**Not the simplest argumen but an instructive one:**

Construct a directed graph with vertices $TT$, $TH$, $HT$, $TT$, and an edge
from the vertex $xy$ to the vertices $yH$ and $yT$ (here $x$ and $y$ are
either $H$ or $T$) A path starting at the vertex $TH$ of length $n$ in this
graph corresponds precisely to a sequence in $H$ and $T$ of length $n+2$
starting with $TH$, and similarly for other starting vertices; for example,
the path $TH\to HH\to HH\to HT\to TT$ corresponds to the sequence $THHHTT$.

Now introduce a variable $q$, and consider the matrix
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\q&0&q&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix},$$ the
the column vector $w=(1,q,1,1)$ and the row
$\def\uu{\mathbf1}\uu=(1,1,1,1)$. Now the $i$th entry of the vector $B^nw$
is a polynomial in $q$ such that the coefficient of $q^r$ in it is the
number of sequences of length $n+2$ of $H$s and $T$s which have exactly $r$
appearances of $TH$. You can prove this by induction.

Similarly, $\uu B^n w$ is a polynomial in $q$ such that the coefficient
of $q^r$ is the number of sequences of length $n+2$ of $H$s and $T$s which
contain exactly $r$ appearances of $TH$.
Then $\def\d{\tfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq}}2^{-(n+2)}\d(\uu
B^nw)\big|_{q=1}$ is the expected number $\alpha_{n+2}$ of $TH$s in sequences
of length $n+2$.

Consider next the series 
$F(t,q)=\tfrac14\sum_{n\geq0}\uu B^n wt^n/2^n$. This can be rewritten
simply as $$F(t,q)=\tfrac14\uu(1-Bt/2)^{-1} w$$ and from this we can
actually compute that $$F(t,q)=\frac{-q (t+1)+t-3}{t ((q-1) t+4)-4}.$$
It follows that $$\d F(t,q)=\frac{4}{\left((q-1) t^2+4 t-4\right)^2}$$
and evaluating this at $q=1$ we get $$\d F(t,q)\big|_{q=1}=\frac{1}{4
(t-1)^2}=\tfrac14\sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)t^n$$ and we therefore conclude that the
number we are after is $$\alpha_n=\frac{n-1}4.$$

Comment: i know how expected value works, i just dont' know how to find them all

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, the occurrences of HT and TH will, on average, be the same. Therefore we can find the expected number of *both* and then average the two.

Clearly the way to get either a HT or a TH is to switch the event. After the first flip, we will switch on average $$\frac{n-1}{2}$$ times. Dividing this in half gives $$\text{Expected HT}=\frac{n-1}{4}$$ which is consistent with the $3.75=(16-1)/4$ that I got in my simulation (see the comment I put on the post).

Following the argument suggested by Mariano, there are $2^n$ possible sequences in all. If we fix the $i$'th spot and demand that a HT occurs there, we are free to pick the other $n-2$ spots however we like, so the probability of any given spot having the HT is just $$\frac{2^{n-2}}{2^n}=\frac{1}{4}$$ Since there are $n-1$ possible spots, we get $$\frac{n-1}{4}$$ again as the expected value.

I also ran a test with $25$ flips and got $\approx 6$ which is $(25-1)/4$ so I think your formula is incorrect or some kind of approximation.